# List item not hidden by jQuery hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a leaderboard feature to my website, but unfortunately the minimum score functionality for the leaderboard is not fully working.

So I have created a select element that triggers the setMinScore function which looks through each list element and hides it if its input.dial-list contains a value that is less than the minimum score - basically I want to show only list items that have scores greater than the minimum score.

However, two of my list items that have scores of "8" are still shown in the list when I select any minimum score apart from 80 and 90 (e.g. if I select 70 the list items are shown though they have inputs with values less than 70; but if I select 80 or 90, the items are not shown anymore so the functionality is working only for 80 and 90).

```
<select name="candList<?php echo $job['jobId']; ?>" onchange="setMinScore(this)">
 <option value="0">0</option>
 <option value="10">10</option>
 <option value="20">20</option>
 <option value="30">30</option>
 <option value="40">40</option>
 <option value="50" selected>50</option>
 <option value="60">60</option>
 <option value="70">70</option>
 <option value="80">80</option>
 <option value="90">90</option>
</select>

<li>
 <span class="list-content">
 <div class="dial-list-holder">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['score']; ?>" class="dial-list">
 </div>
 <div class="dial-list-holder">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['matchScore']; ?>" class="dial-list-match">
 </div>
 <div class="name">
  <h5><?php echo $row['name']; ?></h5>
 </div>
 </span>
</li>
```

And this is the javascript function:

```
function setMinScore(selectEl)
{
 var minScore = $(selectEl).val();
 var candList = "."+$(selectEl).attr('name');

 $(candList).find('li').each(function() {

 if($(this).find('input.dial-list').val() < minScore) { 
  $(this).hide();  
 } 
 else { 
  $(this).show();    
 }
 });
}
```

Thanks guys, your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would add an id to select element and get the selected value in this was:

```
var minScore = $("#id option:selected").val();
```

instead of yours:

```
var minScore = $(selectEl).val();
```

Comment: Thanks, Gorazd! I've tried var selectId = "#"+$(selectEl).attr('id'); var minScore = $(selectId+" option:selected").val(); but it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Can you put your code and what you tried on http://jsfiddle.net/. It will be much easier to help you.